# Web based forum software using web sockets and json-rpc

Tags: web-apps, web-services, forum, json

Looking for an full-featured web based forum software (like phpBB or such), with the following features:

- the server sends the basic forum-page, with the basic page layout, what will contain the needed javascript and CSS
- from this moment every communication between the browser and server is done via WebSockets (mandatory)
- and over the web socket channel uses json-rpc for getting/sending the forum content (messages)... (optional, would be nice - but it could use plain-old ajax/json)

Needed it for studying purpose, so the server side could be implemented in any language or framework (node.js, python, perl and such - only no Java please).